# Pyspark parquet file sizes are drastically different

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, bigdata, parquet

I use pyspark to process a fix set of data records on a daily basis and store them as 16 parquet files in a Hive table using the date as partition. In theory, the number of records every day should be on the same order of magnitude showing below, about 1.2 billion rows and it is indeed on the same order.

[image]

When I look at the parquet files, the size of every parquet files in each day is around 86MB like 2019-09-04 showing below

[image]

But one thing I noticed to be very strange is the date of 2019-08-03, the file size is 10x larger than the files in other date, but the number of records seems to be more or less the same. I am so confused and could not come up with a reason for it. If you have any idea as to why, please share it with me. Thank you.

[image]

I've just realised that the way I saved the data for 2019-08-03 is as follows

```
cols = sparkSession \
.sql("SELECT * FROM {} LIMIT 1".format(table_name)).columns

df.select(cols).write.insertInto(table_name, overwrite=True)
```

For other days

```
insertSQL = """
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE {}
PARTITION(crawled_at_ds = '{}')
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
FROM calendarCrawlsDF
"""

sparkSession.sql(
    insertSQL.format(table_name,
                     calendarCrawlsDF.take(1)[0]["crawled_at_ds"]))
```

For 2019-08-03, I used Dataframe **insertInto** method. For other days, I used sparkSession sql to execute **INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE**

Could this be the reason?

Comment: maybe you use snappy compression ? or another one ?

Comment: what do you mean? Nothing has changed for those days. But the file size are so different.

Comment: just a lead. But that's probably something else. Parquet is columnar file type. Therefore, if your data can be compressed more on a column, that could be the reason ... Size does not depend on the number of records

Comment: What you are saying is on 2019-08-03 somehow the data cannot be compressed as much as other days? The data type has not changed at all.

Comment: yep, that's exactly what i'm saying

Comment: You are right I think. I just updated my answer at the bottom. The way I save the data for those days are different. It could be the cause. But why it could be so drastically different?

Comment: I run into the same case. The file size is drastically different if I save in different way. (but same format)